# Running multiple expect/TCL code inside same shell script

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I have to run multiple chunks of `expect` script inside the shell script. In between each expect scripts, I have to run shell code. Below is conceptual non-working code where, 1st chunk would SSH into a remote node, and the subsequent chunks will run some other commands on the same remote server.

```
#!/bin/bash

#first chunk of expect code
/usr/bin/expect - <<EOF
    global spawn_id
    spawn /bin/bash
    expect -re ".*\$"
    spawn -- "ssh   -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no admin@localstack1\r"
    expect -re  ".*assword.*"
    send 'admin\r'
    expect -re ".*\$"
    interact
EOF

#running shell commands
ls -lrt


#2nd chunk of expect code

/usr/bin/expect - <<EOF
    expect -re ".*\$"
    send -- "hostname\r"
    expect -re ".*\$"
EOF
```

This seems to be impossible, However would like to know more from experts.  unlike `pexepct`, here I am unable to find any way to reuse the spawned shell(passing the child object).

why?

from another program I am getting the list of commands,expected_results and timeout , so I cannot hardcode them within the  expect script. Sometime there are 1 set of commands,sometimes multiple set of commands.

Comment: you are right that's a limitation when using Expect unless you write all your script in Expect/Tcl (just like you do all the things with Python when using `pexpect`). you can try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) which is specifically designed to be used in shell scripts.

Comment: Expect is using Tcl which is also a general purpose programming language. You can use Tcl's [exec](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.html) to run Linux commands (e.g. your `ls -lrt`).

Comment: If you do it all in tcl you don't need `ls` at all; you can get and sort filenames directly in it.

Comment: In this case I would write the whole program in Tcl, and shell out only for those commands where you want to use bash.

Comment: Note that the first `spawn` of bash appears redundant, it's unrelated to the second `spawn` which starts ssh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of writing the whole thing in Expect/Tcl as suggested in the comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

#spawn /bin/bash
#expect -re ".*\$"
spawn -- "ssh   -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no admin@localstack1\r"
expect -re  ".*assword.*"
send 'admin\r'
expect -re ".*\$"
interact

#running shell commands
puts [exec ls -lrt]

expect -re ".*\$"
send -- "hostname\r"
expect -re ".*\$"
```

I've commented out the `spawn` of bash because that appears redundant.

Comment: are you sure `spawn -- "ssh   -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no admin@localstack1\r"` would work?

Comment: Good point, that line should be changed to
`spawn -- ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no admin@localstack1`.

Comment: `spawn` even does not support `--`.

Comment: You're right of course, `--` should be omitted also.  I suspect this line in the original script was meant to be a `send`.

Comment: and usually after `interact` returns, the spawned process would have exited so you cannot call `send`/`expect` any more.

Comment: `send 'admin\r'` is not correct because `'` has not special meaning in Tcl. should be `send "admin\r"` or just `send admin\r`

Comment: `expect -re ".*\$"` does not look very correct. it's basically no-op since it matches anything even if the buffer is empty.

Comment: These points are also true, but just stuff I copied from the original script.  I was mainly trying to show how to invert the shell/expect relationship, and I think I made that point.